# Asymptotics of $F(\varepsilon)=\int^b_0\frac{dx}{\varepsilon +\phi(x)}$ as $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$ where $\phi(x)\sim Ax$ as $x\rightarrow0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, asymptotics, lebesgue-integral

This is one part of an old qualifier analysis problem that I am trying to complete.

> Suppose $\phi$ is a continuous function on a finite interval $[0,b]$ and that $\phi(x)>0$ for all $x\in[0,b]$. Assume that $\phi(x)\sim A x^r$ for some constant $A>0$ and $r\geq0$.
> Define
> $$F(\varepsilon)=\int^b_0 \frac{dx}{\varepsilon + \phi(x)}$$
>
> 1. If $0\leq r<1$, then $\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}=\int^b_0\frac{dx}{\phi(x)}<\infty$.
> 2. If $r>1$, then
>    $$F(\varepsilon)\sim \frac{\pi}{r A^{1/r}\sin(\pi/r)} \varepsilon^{-(1-\frac1r)}\quad\text{as}\quad\varepsilon\rightarrow0$$
> 3. If $r=1$, then
>    $$F(\varepsilon)\sim\frac{1}{A}\log(\varepsilon^{-1})\quad\text{as}\quad\varepsilon\rightarrow0$$

Part (1) is a simple application of monotone convergence.

When $r\geq1$, $\lim_{\varepsilon0}F(\varepsilon)=\infty$ by monotone convergence.

Part (2) I have done by first applying the  of variable $u=\varepsilon^{-1}x^r$, followed by application of dominated convergence. All that gives
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\varepsilon^{1-\frac1r}F(\varepsilon)=\int^\infty_0\frac{u^{\frac1r-1}}{1+Au}\,du$$
The later is a integral of the Mellin transform type and the expression in the problem can be obtained by complex contour integration.

Part (3) is where I am having difficulties.  The asymptotic seems given in the problem seems correct. By assuming that $\phi(t)=At$, then a direct computation gives
$$F(\varepsilon)=\frac{1}{A}\log\Big(\frac1A+\frac{b}{\varepsilon}\Big)\sim\frac{1}{A}\log(\varepsilon^{-1})$$
I thing dominated convergence still useful but a trick may be needed. For example, the function $x\mapsto x^{-1}\phi(x)$ can be extended to $[0,b]$ as a strictly positive continuous function on $[0,b]$ and so, there is $M>0$ such that $\phi(x)\geq Bx$ for $x\in[0,b]$. Hence
$$\frac{1}{\varepsilon +\phi(x)}\leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon+Bx}$$

Any hints (not necessarily a complete solution) are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Given any $0 < t < A$ there's a $\delta > 0$ such that $(A - t)x^r < \phi(x) < (A + t)x^r$ when $x < \delta$. Insert this into the $x < \delta$ portion of the integral and you'll get lower and upper bounds for this part of the integral which will be close to the asymptotics you need as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. The $x > \delta$ integral will be an error term as $\epsilon$ goes to zero.  Letting $t \rightarrow 0$ gives the desired asymptotics.

Comment: I will put your hint to the test.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it seems that integral over $[\delta, b]$ is not easy to balace or control. I'll think a little more about how to split the interval more efficiently.

Comment: As $\epsilon$ goes to zero it converges to $\int_t^b {1 \over \phi(x)}\,dx$... it doesn't even increase to infinity.

Comment: Ah! I see it now. It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If assuming that $\phi(t) = At$ directly yields the desired asymptotics, then one natural strategy would be to control the error of this assumption. Namely, we consider
$$
\frac{1}{\epsilon + \phi(t)} = \frac{1}{\epsilon + At} + \frac{At - \phi(t)}{(\epsilon + \phi(t))(\epsilon + At)}.
$$
Then it remains to show that
$$
\int_0^b \frac{At - \phi(t)}{(\epsilon + \phi(t))(\epsilon + At)}dt
$$
is asymptotically subdominant to $\frac{1}{A}\log(\epsilon^{-1})$. Now, it's not entirely clear to me what definition of the notation $\phi(t) \sim At$ is being used here, but I would presume you could use it to control the numerator here, and consequently the integral overall.

Comment: In my posting,  $f(t)\sim g(t)$ as $t\rightarrow t_0$ if  $\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}=1$.

Comment: In that case, multiplying and dividing the numerator by $At$ gives a numerator $At(1-\phi(t)/At)$. I suppose $t_0$ (or $x_0$, sorry I randomly changed the integration variable) would be $0$? The $At$ could be cancelled by the $\epsilon + At$, so we're basically looking at an integrand which is $(1-\phi(t)/At) / (\epsilon + \phi(t))$. The behavior near $0$ should then be well controlled by the assumed behavior of $\phi$, so I think you could now do something similar to what you've already done.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain two different methods that I have now to solved this problem. The first is based on Zarrax's solution above.

I have already established in my posting that there is $B>0$ scuch that $\phi(x)\geq Bx$ or all $x\in[0,b]$.

**Method 1:** For any $0<t<<1$ chose $\delta_t>0$ such that $(A-t)x<\phi(x)<(A+t)x$ for all $0<t<\delta$.
Then
$$\frac{1}{\varepsilon+(A+t)x}<\frac{1}{\varepsilon+\phi(x)}<\frac{1}{\varepsilon+(A-t)x}\quad\text{for}\quad 0<x<\delta$$
Splitting the the interval of integration gives
$$\frac{1}{\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\int^b_0\frac{dx}{\varepsilon+\phi(x)}=\frac{1}{\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\int^\delta_0\frac{dx}{\varepsilon+\phi(x)} +\frac{1}{\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\int^b_\delta\frac{dx}{\varepsilon+\phi(x)}$$

The second term on the right-hand side is small, that is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\int^b_\delta\frac{dx}{\varepsilon +\phi(x)}&\leq \frac{1}{\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\int^b_\delta\frac{dx}{\varepsilon+Bx}\\
&=\frac{1}{B\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\log\Big(\frac{\varepsilon+Bb}{\varepsilon+B\delta}\Big)\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}0
\end{align*}

The first terms has bounds
$$\frac{1}{(A+t)\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\log\Big(\frac{\varepsilon+(A+t)\delta}{\varepsilon}\Big)\leq \frac{1}{\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\int^\delta_0\frac{dx}{\varepsilon +\phi(x)}\leq  \frac{1}{(A-t)\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\log\Big(\frac{\varepsilon+(A-t)\delta}{\varepsilon}\Big)
$$
Letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow\infty$ gives

$$
\frac{1}{A+t}\leq\liminf_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\int^b_0\frac{dx}{\varepsilon+\phi(x)}\leq\limsup_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\int^b_0\frac{dx}{\varepsilon+\phi(x)}\leq\frac{1}{A-t}
$$
for all $0<t\ll 1$. Ir follows that
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}\int^b_0\frac{dx}{\varepsilon +\phi(x)}=\frac{1}{A}
$$

**Method 2:**
This I found from a hint given by one of may study mates. Split the interval of integration as follows
$$\int^b_0\frac{dx}{\varepsilon+\phi(x)}=\int^{\varepsilon b}_0+\int^b_{\varepsilon b}\frac{dx}{\varepsilon+\phi(x)}$$
The first itnegral can be bounded as
\begin{align}
\int^{\varepsilon b}_0\frac{dx}{\varepsilon+\phi(x)}&\leq\int^{\varepsilon b}_0\frac{dx}{\varepsilon + Bx}\\
&=\frac{1}{B}\log(1+Bb)<\infty
\end{align}
Since $F(0+)=\infty$,
$$F(\varepsilon)\sim \int^b_{\varepsilon b}\frac{dx}{\varepsilon + \phi(x)}$$
The change of variables $x(t)=b\varepsilon^t$ (equivalently $t=\frac{\log(b^{-1}x)}{\log \varepsilon}$) gives
\begin{align*}
\int^b_{\varepsilon b}\frac{dx}{\varepsilon + \phi(x)}&=\log(\varepsilon^{-1})\int^1_0\frac{b\varepsilon^t}{\varepsilon + \phi(b\varepsilon^t)}\,dt
\end{align*}

Since $\frac{b\varepsilon^t}{\varepsilon + \phi(b\varepsilon^t)}\leq \frac{b\varepsilon^t}{\varepsilon + Bb\varepsilon^t}=\frac{b}{\varepsilon^{1-t}+Bb}\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{B}$, by dominated convergence
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\int^1_0\frac{b\varepsilon^t}{\varepsilon + \phi(b\varepsilon^t)}\,dt=\frac1{A}
\end{align*}
In conclussion, $F(\varepsilon)\sim \frac{1}{\log(\varepsilon^{-1})}$.